# Magento Add translation file to custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9, template, localisation

i've added a custom translation to my Magento theme like below :

i've add `translation.csv` in :

`app/design/frontend/themename/default/local/ar_SA`

and in

`app/design/frontend/themename/default/local/ar_US`

the format of `translation.csv` like below:

```
"Add To Cart","Buy"
"Add To Compare","Compare"
```

And from the admin i've choose the `local Options` for `specific language` from :

```
System->Configuration->General->Local Options
```

But the translation doesn't working !! any suggetions about that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your foldername is

```
app/design/frontend/themename/default/locale/ar_SA
```

Note local > **locale**